# Join from a deep hashref in perl

Tags: perl

I have a function called `scrape_html` what returns an array of deep hashrefs.

The next code prints the correct result:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

for my $table (scrape_html()) {
        say join("\t",
                $table->{tr}->[0]->{td}->[1],
                $table->{tr}->[2]->{td}->[1],
                $table->{tr}->[4]->{td}->[1],
        );
}
```

it prints, for example:

```
r0c1    r2c1    r4c1
```

I want make it shorter with cleaner row numbers, like the next:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

for my $table (scrape_html()) {
    say $table->{tr}->[$_]->{td}->[1] for (qw(0 2 4) );
}
```

This prints:

```
r0c1
r2c1
r4c1
```

The problem is - how to join it? The next code

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

for my $table (scrape_html()) {
    say join("\t",
        (
        $table->{tr}->[$_]->{td}->[1] for (qw(0 2 4) )
        )
    );
}
```

says:

```
syntax error at soex.pl line 7, near "] for "
Execution of soex.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What is the correct syntax?

If someone want a demo of scrape_html

```
sub scrape_html {
return (
    {
          'tr' => [
                    {
                      'td' => [
                                'r0c0',
                                'r0c1'
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                      'td' => [
                                'r1c0',
                                'r1c1',
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                      'td' => [
                                'r2c0',
                                'r2c1'
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                      'td' => [
                                'r3c0',
                                'r3c1'
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                      'td' => [
                                'r4c0',
                                'r4c1'
                              ]
                    },
                    {
                      'td' => [
                                'r5c0',
                                'r5c1'
                              ]
                    },
                  ]
        }
);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `map` which returns transformed elements,

```
say join("\t",
    (
    map $table->{tr}->[$_]->{td}->[1],  qw(0 2 4)
    )
);
```

Comment: omg - i'm stupid and fully forgot the `map`. Thank you acceting in 10 minutes.. ;)